# jquery ui slider with two handles returns wrong index of handle

Tags: jquery-ui, indexing, slider, handles

I am using the jquery-ui slider with 2 handles.
But when I move the right handle on top of the left handle and after that, grab the top handle, the bottom one is selected.

This error also occur when I move one handle in the vertical axis.

```
 $('#slider').slider({
  min: 0.0,
  max: 10,
  step: 0.1,
  values: [5, 5],
});
```

css

```
#slider .ui-state-default:nth-of-type(1) {
  border: solid 2px red;
  top:25px;
}

#slider .ui-state-default:nth-of-type(2) {
  border: solid 2px blue;
}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kaq1z2xh/)

Why is jquery-ui returning the wrong index? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to setup a `range` slider? By default, it only sets 1 handle unless `reange: true` option is set.

Comment: Appears to work exactly as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/j279gu8e/

Comment: Can also style it better: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/j279gu8e/1/

Comment: No I do not want to setup a range slider. How can you say @Twisty that it works exactly like expected. When I want to move the bottom blue handle in your fiddle the red one is moving. I was not expecting that. Is that only in chrome?

Comment: Since both handles have the same position, slider lays them on top of each other. I witnessed the same activity in FireFox. You can test this by setting the default value to something like `[4, 6]` for example.

Comment: Yes, that was also my observation.I found this bug in the jquery-ui bug tracker https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9553 , but this is 4 years ago and nothing happens. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: There is a proposed fix. Would have to examine the 1.12.1 code to see if it was accepted. Otherwise apply the fix in your own code.

Comment: I'm not happy with manipulating the jquery-ui code, because of further updates. I think I am going to use different slider not the jquery ones. But thanks for the replies